# Any equivalent of sys.dbms_xmlgen.convert(varchar2,Number) of oracle in postgresql? Because postgresql doesnot support this function

Tags: postgresql

WITH x AS
(SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(REGEXP_REPLACE(iText,
'(#[[:digit:]]+;)',
'\1'),
1) AS message
FROM DUAL)
SELECT UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE(message)into iText2 from x
*/

Comment: What does this function do? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: While a great deal of SQL is the same across RDBMS the same is not true of the RDBMS system as a whole - especially the procedures/functions/types (and in Oracle's case Packages).  You are going to have reverse engineer the Oracle statement and then re engineer to Postgres. Not only does the DBMS_XMLGEN package not exist in Postgres I assure neither does the Package  UTL_I18N.  I further suspect that "iText2" is an Oracle user defined type.so it does not exist either.  Here is hoping you have good internal documentation.  Post specific questions/code when you have them.